# Full height div to fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle

What I would like to do is this:

Create a full height div which go to a fixed top div after scrolling.

```
1) -----------
   |         |
   |         |
   |         |
   |---------|
   |        ?|
   -----------
```

After scroll:

```
2) -----------
   |        ?|
   -----------
```

If you scroll back, you get the full height again.
Or, if you click the ?, you also get the full height.

I could picture it as an extra layer which can respond with the scroll but also toggle back when the question mark is clicked.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Like a fixed header but with a toggle function and 100% height

Comment: no, sorry post some code. Improve your question. As it currently stands it can be translated in too many different things.

Comment: You mean: you want that a DIV fixes at the top of the window once it reaches the top edge?

Comment: like this: 
http://www.derby-web-design-agency.co.uk/tutorials/jQuery-Toggle/#

but it has to start as a 100% height and also depends on the scroll

Comment: "like" this... which part is *"like"* your question? What depends on the scroll? Again... can you please show some CODE? What have you tried so far? You really want one to do it for you?

Comment: See this naked example... http://jsbin.com/seyate/2/edit now again, what should the gray one do?

Comment: What's not clear, is: we scrolled the page and the gray item is fixed. Now we click the toggle button... what should happen to the currently visible elements (the .box ones)? I mean... should the document scroll back to top, or should teh gray DIV open back to full? Cause if it opens back to full than the logical thing to do would be to scroll all back to top...

Answer (score 0):

You can just toggle a div that is fixed to the top. set it to display none by default. Make a button that toggles that div

Comment: You could also put it on the top of the page *not fixed* and toggle hide and show